# Compiling 32-bit OS X binaries on a 64-bit environment

Tags: macos, gcc, compilation, 64-bit, 32-bit

What is involved in compiling 32-bit Intel OS X binaries on a 64-bit command-line environment? Is it as simple as adding a `-m32` flag? I'm not using Xcode, but could use it to install libraries that `gcc` could use, if needed. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're compiling on a Macintosh computer using Apple's implementation of GCC, one of the extra options you can pass along is the "`-arch`" parameter.

[The man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/gcc/) says this:

```
-arch arch
   Compile for the specified target architecture arch.  
   The allowable values are i386, x86_64, ppc and ppc64.  
   Multiple options work, and direct the compiler to produce "universal" 
   binaries including object code for each architecture specified with -arch.  
   This option only works if assembler and libraries are available 
   for each architecture specified.  (APPLE ONLY)
```

Comment: Is `i386` always (and I mean always) 32-bit Intel?

Comment: AFAIK... unless AMD or some other Intel competitor I didn't know about are making chips for Apple computers.

Comment: Okay, I'll give that a shot and see what I can find. Thanks.

Comment: Please update the link for "The man page".

Comment: done @Boris ; gcc doesn't ship by default on Macs anymore, IIRC.  [OpenSource contributors are still "working on it" for M1 macs](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252398918).

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Correct. `gcc` with macOS is actually `clang` unfortunately.